# Search Active Directory Group by GUID using DirectorySearcher

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm using `DirectorySearcher` to find an AD security group by its (object) GUID.

Here's my code so far:

```
using (var container = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://host:port/DC=X,DC=Y", User, Pass, AuthenticationType)
{
   using (var searcher = new DirectorySearcher(container))
   {
      searcher.Filter = $"(objectguid=XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX)"

      var result = searcher.FindOne();
   }
}
```

Unfortunately the result always returns null, and I cannot change the `DirectoryEntry`'s path.

Answer (score 0):

To make a query using `objectGuid` requires a special format that I don't quite remember right now, but it's complicated.

But there's a better way. You can bind directly to the object using the GUID, without searching, by using this format:

```
var result = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://host:port/<GUID=XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX>", User, Pass, AuthenticationType)
```

More information on that here: [Using objectGUID to Bind to an Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ad/using-objectguid-to-bind-to-an-object)

You can do the same with the SID as well: [Binding to an Object Using a SID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ad/binding-to-an-object-using-a-sid)

Answer (score 0):

In order to match the active directory format, I have found the following solution:

```
Guid groupId = new Guid("ed0ec41e-38f9-4826-bfe9-25946bf795ae")
string activeIdFormat = string.Join('\\', BitConverter
            .ToString(groupId.ToByteArray())
            .Split("-"))
        .Insert(0, "\\");

// "\\1E\\C4\\0E\\ED\\F9\\38\\26\\48\\BF\\E9\\25\\94\\6B\\F7\\95\\AE"
string searchFilter=$"(&(objectCategory=group)(objectGUID={activeIdFormat}))";
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**